# wrapfigure error

Tags: memoir, wrapfigure

I'm using `memoir` (a beautiful `documentclass` that gets me in trouble too often)... and I'm trying to use `wrapfigure`.

This is what I use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,openright,final,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}    

\begin{wrapfigure}{./Images/13-SubdivisionRule}{o}{width=0.5\textwidth}
\caption[Shape Grammar Subdivision]{The subdivision of a surface by shape grammars for fabrication of the sheets \cite{shelden02}}
\label{SubdivisionSG}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Package wrapfig Warning: wrapfigure used inside a conflicting environment on in
put line 129.
```

Comment: The code you just posted won't produce the warning mentioned; it will produce an error since the `wrapfigure` environment is being used in the wrong way (see my answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using wrapfigure in the wrong way; the syntax for this environment is

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[<number of lines>]{<placement>}[<overhang>]{<width>} 
<figure commands> 
\end{wrapfigure}
```

so, you you can use something like the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,openright,final,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}    

\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics{./Images/13-SubdivisionRule}
\caption[Shape Grammar Subdivision]{The subdivision of a surface by shape grammars for fabrication of the sheets \cite{shelden02}}
\label{SubdivisionSG}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

If you are getting the warning

```
Package wrapfig Warning: wrapfigure used inside a conflicting environment on input line 129.
```

then most probably you are using `wrapfigure` inside a list-like environment (`enumerate`, or `itemize`, for example) and the use of the environment is not allowed inside lists.

Comment: Works now. Although I can't control it's position at all, no matter where I put the environment in the file it appears at the end.

Comment: @AymanElmasry: this advice is given in the package documentation: "It is possible that a non-floating wrapfigure will be forced to float when an earlier one is still being processed. A warning will be written in that case. You can
have more information about the floating process written to the log file by specifying
`\usepackage[verbose]{wrapfig}`". So check your .log file for any messages/warnings about `wrapfigure`.