# Too much space around wrap figure

Tags: spacing, floats, wrapfigure

I am using the `wrapfig` package to have my text around the figure but there is too much space around it as you can see below.

[image: example of too much space]

Here is the code that I am using, I looked at the wikibook on LaTeX for this issue and it suggested that I use `\vspace{-xpt}` to decrease the amount but it's not working very well. Here is the code for `wrapfig`.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\vspace{-20pt}
\centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Program_Layout.png}
\vspace{-10pt}
\caption{Basic layout}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

How can I fix the code such so the text can get as close as possible?

Comment: Does the image have white-space to it's left side ? Or is the image just that window screenshot ?

Comment: @Razor No, there is no whitespace around the image. The image just the window.

Comment: I had a similar problem and fixed it using `\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{*insert number here* \textwidth}`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Instead of using the `scale` option for `\includegraphics`, you could use `width` and select the same width that was declared for the `wrapfigure` environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Program_Layout.png}
\vspace{-10pt}
\caption{Basic layout}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the first optional argument, then you can even suggest the appropriate number of lines:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[11]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Program_Layout.png}
\vspace{-10pt}
\caption{Basic layout}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: Can we decrease more horizontal space between text and figure?

Comment: Is there a way to set the Margins around `\caption{Basic layout}` to be minimal?

Comment: You can use `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Program_Layout.png}`. If you then want to change the width of the figure, you have to change it only in a single place.

Answer (score 47):

The spacing around the `wrapfigure` is given by two lengths: `\columnsep` (for horizontal padding) and `\intextsep` (for vertical padding). Here's an example illustrating the difference between the default and setting them all to `0pt`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,wrapfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,lipsum,wrapfig}
\begin{document}
% Default settings
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Basic layout}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

% Adjusted settings
\begingroup
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Basic layout}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

The default for `\columnsep` is `10pt`, while `\intextsep` is `12.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt`. The following is taken from the [`wrapfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf) (section **2 Sizing and optional overhang**, p 3):

> LaTeX will wrap surrounding text around the ﬁgure, leaving a gap of `\intextsep` at
>   the top and bottom, and `\columsep` at the side, by producing a series of shortened text
>   lines beside the ﬁgure. The indentation (shortening) of the text is the ﬁgure width plus
>   `\columnsep` minus overhang (if any; see below).
>
> LaTeX calculates the number of short lines needed based on the height of the ﬁgure and
>   the length `\intextsep`. You can override this guess by giving the ﬁrst optional argument
>   (parameter `#1`) specifying the number of shortened lines (counting each displayed equation
>   as 3 lines). This is particularly useful when the surrounding text contains extra vertical
>   spacing that is not accounted for automatically.

So, barring that you don't have any whitespace around your actual image, you can also adjust `\columnsep` and `\intextsep` to your liking for any particular `wrapfigure`.

Comment: In `\begingroup` I got the error https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55563/wrapfigure-error

Comment: with more recent lipsum you need to add a paragraph break before the `\endgroup` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/635953/1090