# Wrapping two figures in one paragraph

Tags: wrapfigure

I am trying to wrap two pictures in a paragraph, as shown in the two images below. The two red boxes show the desired locations for the two figures.[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot get the following code to work what I am looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{3cm}
    \centering
    \rule{3cm}{3cm}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{3cm}
    \centering
    \rule{3cm}{3cm}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

How can I exactly specify the locations of the `wrapfigure`s?

Comment: Consider a direct implementation of `\parshape`.

Comment: Or, you can copy Werner's solution to this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111393/too-much-space-around-wrap-figure, but it implies to cut the paragraph.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a manual manipulation using `\parshape`. Since you didn't provide actual measurements of the images to be included, your setup will most likely be slightly different. However, the usage would be very similar:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133660/5764
\makeatletter
\def\newparshape{\parshape\@npshape0{}}
\def\@npshape#1#2#3{\ifx\\#3\expandafter\@@@npshape\else\expandafter\@@npshape\fi
  {#1}{#2}{#3}}
\def\@@npshape#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum#3>\z@\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {\expandafter\@@npshape\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2 #4 #5}{\numexpr#3-1\relax}{#4}{#5}}%
  {\@npshape{#1}{#2}}}
\def\@@@npshape#1#2#3{#1 #2 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae mauris risus. Sed 
varius dui diam, sit amet volutpat risus euismod in. Ut ac dui fermentum, laoreet arcu 
volutpat, vestibulum urna. Integer vitae odio at neque imperdiet sollicitudin vel vel enim. 
Nullam sodales facilisis magna sit amet tempor. Morbi ut nulla sem. Aliquam sagittis, 
lacus auctor tincidunt semper, odio dui lacinia lectus, quis tempus quam leo sed mi. 
Maecenas eu mauris dolor.

% Placement of top-left image
\newparshape
  {5}{\dimexpr3cm+\tabcolsep}{\dimexpr\textwidth-3cm-\tabcolsep}% Unique to top-left image
  {3}{0pt}{\textwidth}% full-width lines where no image is present
  {6}{0pt}{\dimexpr\textwidth-3cm-\tabcolsep}\\% Unique to bottom-right image
\noindent\leavevmode
\llap{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=4.5\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}%
  \hspace*{\tabcolsep}}%
Pellentesque porta pharetra leo, ut accumsan diam feugiat sit amet. Ut mattis nulla sed 
sapien suscipit, eu sodales elit cursus. Vestibulum sit amet sollicitudin nisl. Aenean 
vestibulum purus sed tincidunt convallis. Aliquam ut sodales risus. Mauris in mauris a 
ante venenatis faucibus. Ut nunc ante, cursus sit amet iaculis eget, imperdiet quis libero. 
Pellentesque laoreet dolor eget consectetur vehicula. Maecenas ultrices vehicula ultricies. 
Morbi cursus risus ut eros placerat condimentum. Mauris nec varius lectus. Nulla adipiscing 
porttitor tellus vitae congue. Aliquam commodo gravida erat, lacinia vehicula enim mollis 
nec. Nulla sed metus gravida, faucibus neque eu, rutrum purus. Integer ornare nunc vel 
dolor lacinia, sit amet venenatis turpis porttitor. Fusce lobortis magna eget odio iaculis, 
sed blandit urna dictum.%
% Placement of bottom-right image
\hfill\rlap{\hspace*{\tabcolsep}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+5\baselineskip+\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=4.5\baselineskip]{example-image-b}}}

Morbi id dolor vulputate, euismod sapien nec, condimentum tellus. Fusce tincidunt sem non 
turpis ultricies, eu egestas lorem posuere. Integer risus lectus, gravida vel tincidunt sit 
amet, vestibulum eget leo. Curabitur vitae enim sem. Vivamus rutrum velit eget justo 
condimentum egestas. Phasellus sit amet lacus mauris. Sed quis aliquet tellus. In mauris 
ante, porttitor sit amet rhoncus et, ultrices quis elit. Proin sed aliquet eros.
\end{document}
```

We first set the layout of the paragraph which shape has to be changed using `\newparshape{<num>}{<indent>}{<width>}...{<num>}{<indent>}{<width>}\\`. So, using the code above, we set 3 different line definitions:

- `{5}` lines with an indent of `3cm+\tabcolsep` (to avoid overwriting the actual image) and a width of `\textwidth-3cm-\tabcolsep` (the remainder of `\textwidth` minus the width of the image and the gap between the image and text);
- `{3}` lines with no indent (`0pt`) and full width (`\textwidth`); and
- `{6}` lines with no indent (`0pt`) and width `\textwidth-3cm-\tabcolsep`.

Remember that we have to set the paragraph shape *before* the paragraph starts.

The top-left image is placed just before the paragraph, while the bottom-right image is placed at the end of the paragraph. Both images are dropped/raised (using `\raisebox{<height>}`) into position based on the number on

- the number of lines they occupy,
- their height, and
- the height of `\strutbox`.

Essentially they're positioned in such a way that they both have zero height/depth (resulting from the `[0pt][0pt]` arguments to `\raisebox`).

`\tabcolsep` is the horizontal gap between the image(s) and the text.

`\newparshape` was taken from [More condensed version of `\parshape`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127504/5764).

I've added a `\noindent`, but that is probably up to you whether you want to use it or not.

---

Here is a different setup where the two images share some common shortened lines within the same paragraph:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133660/5764
\makeatletter
\def\newparshape{\parshape\@npshape0{}}
\def\@npshape#1#2#3{\ifx\\#3\expandafter\@@@npshape\else\expandafter\@@npshape\fi
  {#1}{#2}{#3}}
\def\@@npshape#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum#3>\z@\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {\expandafter\@@npshape\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2 #4 #5}{\numexpr#3-1\relax}{#4}{#5}}%
  {\@npshape{#1}{#2}}}
\def\@@@npshape#1#2#3{#1 #2 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae mauris risus. Sed 
varius dui diam, sit amet volutpat risus euismod in. Ut ac dui fermentum, laoreet arcu 
volutpat, vestibulum urna. Integer vitae odio at neque imperdiet sollicitudin vel vel enim. 
Nullam sodales facilisis magna sit amet tempor. Morbi ut nulla sem. Aliquam sagittis, 
lacus auctor tincidunt semper, odio dui lacinia lectus, quis tempus quam leo sed mi. 
Maecenas eu mauris dolor.

\newparshape
  {7}{\dimexpr3cm+\tabcolsep}{\dimexpr\textwidth-3cm-\tabcolsep}% Unique to top-left image
  {2}{\dimexpr3cm+\tabcolsep}{\dimexpr\textwidth-6cm-2\tabcolsep}% Between top-left and bottom-right image
  {6}{0pt}{\dimexpr\textwidth-3cm-\tabcolsep}\\% Unique to bottom-right image
\noindent\leavevmode
\llap{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=9\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}%
  \hspace*{\tabcolsep}}%
Pellentesque porta pharetra leo, ut accumsan diam feugiat sit amet. Ut mattis nulla sed 
sapien suscipit, eu sodales elit cursus. Vestibulum sit amet sollicitudin nisl. Aenean 
vestibulum purus sed tincidunt convallis. Aliquam ut sodales risus. Mauris in mauris a 
ante venenatis faucibus. Ut nunc ante, cursus sit amet iaculis eget, imperdiet quis libero. 
Pellentesque laoreet dolor eget consectetur vehicula. Maecenas ultrices vehicula ultricies. 
Morbi cursus risus ut eros placerat condimentum. Mauris nec varius lectus. Nulla adipiscing 
porttitor tellus vitae congue. Aliquam commodo gravida erat, lacinia vehicula enim mollis 
nec. Nulla sed metus gravida, faucibus neque eu, rutrum purus. Integer ornare nunc vel 
dolor lacinia, sit amet venenatis turpis porttitor. Fusce lobortis magna eget odio iaculis, 
sed blandit urna dictum.
\hfill\rlap{\hspace*{\tabcolsep}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+8\baselineskip+\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=9\baselineskip]{example-image-b}}}

Morbi id dolor vulputate, euismod sapien nec, condimentum tellus. Fusce tincidunt sem non 
turpis ultricies, eu egestas lorem posuere. Integer risus lectus, gravida vel tincidunt sit 
amet, vestibulum eget leo. Curabitur vitae enim sem. Vivamus rutrum velit eget justo 
condimentum egestas. Phasellus sit amet lacus mauris. Sed quis aliquet tellus. In mauris 
ante, porttitor sit amet rhoncus et, ultrices quis elit. Proin sed aliquet eros.
\end{document}
```

Comment: All right, what I do not like is that you need to handle many internal commands of *LaTeX* (or other *package*) and to use *TeX* primitives to reach this. It would be interesting to implement it in a package or to improve `wrapfig`. To non-expert user is difficult to remember this.

Comment: @skpblack: Oh well, now you can't please everyone, can you. You can write up a package and post an answer here when it becomes available, if you're interested. ;)

Comment: It seems it needs a lot of calculations to be able to put it into the desired place. would there potentially another approach rather than `\parshape`? Is it also possible to add a caption to the figures?

Comment: @A2009: Don't get bowled over by `\newparshape`. Read the post [More condensed version of `\parshape`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127504/5764) to understand the input. Then the trouble is only fiddling around with the location. Your setup is non-standard, so anything you try may have to require some finicky coding...

Comment: Would it be possible to elaborate more on the coding? I kind of understood the post on `\parshape` but its implementation on here is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: @A2009: I've added some elaboration...

Comment: @Werner: Wonderful explanations. I also understand that we can move up and down using `\raisebox` but I don't get what `[0pt][0pt]` arguments do for `\raisebox` in terms of height/depth. Also, I read about `\llap`. It makes its argument stick out to the left of the current point. Is this point the start of the text?

Comment: @A2009: See p 232 of [`source2e`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) - the LaTeX2e kernel documentation where it describes the parameters associated with `\raisebox{<distance>}[<height>][<depth>]{<box>}`. Setting `[0pt][0pt]` makes TeX think the raised content has no height/depth. It avoids possible spacing issues resulting from the vertical moving.

Comment: How about the other question on `\llap`?

Comment: @A2009: `\llap` and `\rlap` are TeX-related commands. The comparable LaTeX2e choices are `\makebox[0pt][r]` and `\makebox[0pt][l]`. So `\llap` sticks out the `l`eft while `\rlap` sticks out to the `r`ight. Never take up any horizontal space (due to the `[0pt]` width of `\makebox`). So yes, the first `\llap` sticks out the left at the start of the paragraph. The second `\rlap` sticks out the right at the end of the paragraph (note that the last line in the paragraph only has width `\textwidth-3cm-\tabcolsep`, so not the full `\textwidth`).

Comment: Thanks. Could you also comment on adding captions to the figures?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16109/discussion-between-a2009-and-werner).