# Using picins to place two figures in one paragraph

Tags: picins

How can I put two figures wrapped around one paragraph using `picins`?

I am using the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\pichskip{15pt}% Horizontal gap between picture and text
\parpic[l][t]{%
  \begin{minipage}{40mm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
    \captionof{figure}{This is figure 1.}
  \end{minipage}
}

\pichskip{15pt}% Horizontal gap between picture and text
\parpic[r][b]{%
  \begin{minipage}{40mm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
    \captionof{figure}{This is figure 2.}
  \end{minipage}
}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

whose result is as follows. Ideally, I want to have figure 1 at the left/top of the paragraph while figure 2 at the bottom/right. How can I place the figures in the desired locations using `picins` package?

[image]

Comment: I think you don't want to hear that, but don't use `picins`. Let your figures/tables flow to an appropriate place.

Comment: I see your point. The reason I thought `picins` would be a better approach is because of the complexities that need to be taken care of in using `\parshape`, as in the answer of the question I posted at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194034/23594.