# Wrapfig MWE giving different results

Tags: graphics, paragraphs, wrapfigure, lipsum

I compiled this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111393/too-much-space-around-wrap-figure#111397) and got a very different result, as shown below.

There's no compilation error, with both TeXstudio and TeXworks, just a bunch of warnings about fonts:

```
/usr/bin/pdflatex (file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map): fontmap entry for `pagd8y' already exists, duplicates ignored
```

I'm on Fedora workstation and use the package manager `dnf install texlive-*` where `*` is the package name.

I do use `wrapfig` in other documents with `tikzpicture` and it works as expected.

Am I missing a package?

**EDIT :** On Overleaf, only the 2nd figure isn't wrapped around and the issue is solved by @DavidCarlisle answer.

**EDIT 2 :** the problem comes from `lipsum` package (version 2021-03-03 v2.3). Replacing `lipsum` paragraphs with text solves the issue. See the comment thread for details. Thanks to @DavidCarlisle.

[image: pdfLaTeX output]
[image: Overleaf output]

Comment: the overprinting in the second one is expected, but he first should have worked.

Comment: You can also use `\WFclear` at the end of a paragraph in case wrapfig isn't **quite** done yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a change to the `lipsum` package, not adding so many `\par` add a blank line before the `\endgroup` after the second example, so `wrapfig` is seen before the paragraph ends.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,wrapfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,lipsum,wrapfig}
\begin{document}
% Default settings
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Basic layout}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

% Adjusted settings
\begingroup
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Basic layout}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: It ain't changing nothing! It did change on Overleaf, but not my machine :(

Comment: then you have something else wrong what version of lipsum and wrapfig are reported in the log ? also what version of latex ? I used an up to date texlive 2022 with `LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1`,  `Package: wrapfig 2003/01/31  v 3.6` and `Package: lipsum 2021-09-20 v2.7 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text` @macxpat

Comment: Package wrapfig : idem ; package lipsum v2.3 (2021-03-03) ; `$latex --version` returns `pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) kpathsea version 6.3.3`.

Comment: @macxpat that's the pdftex binary version,  more relevant is the latex2e version as shown in tke startup at the top of the log in the fom `LaTeX2e <somedate> patch level perhaps`

Comment: Here's the full log: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.1.23)`    `LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4`    `L3 programming layer <2021-05-07>`

Comment: what happens if you don't use lipsum and just write some literal txt there `one two three` repated  a few times, with a blank line at the end? that wouldl cut out the lipsum update @macxpat

Comment: @macxpat it's possible that wrapfig was broken by that latex release (there were some changes to paragraph handling) that got fixed, I can't easily check now, will look later

Comment: Yes, indeed. Replacing lipsum paragraphs with some text solve the problem : text properly wraps around the figures.

Comment: @macxpat OK let's call this done then, after being stable for years there were a few updates to lipsum around that time it's probably not worth worrying about or you could get the latest from ctan and use that rather than your linux texlive version