# lstinline with breaklines=true conflicts with wrapfig, causing warnings

Tags: listings, warnings, wrapfigure

The following MWE shows a warning, printed below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\lstset{breaklines=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{wrapfigure}

Etiam ac quam dui. \lstinline{test}

\end{document}
```

```
Package wrapfig Warning: wrapfigure used inside a conflicting environment on input line 14.
```

Removing the `breaklines` option gets rid of the warning.  Not using `lstinline` in the paragraph immediately following the `wrapfigure` environment also removes the warning.

The warning is repeated once per use of `lstinline` in the paragraph.

The output looks OK. **Is it safe to ignore the warning? Is there a way to use `lstinline` with `breaklines=true` after a `wrapfigure` environment?**

I looked at related questions, such as [wrapfigure error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55563/wrapfigure-error) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677433/how-do-i-correctly-insert-an-image-figure-and-have-the-text-flow-around-the-im, but both boil down to incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wrapfig` issues this warning in a `\parshape` redefinition when it detects that the paragraph shape has been changed to something that doesn't look similar to its own internal format. This hook is only active as long as a paragraph hasn't been wrapped completely to cover the current `wrapfigure`. The problem here is that `listings` changes the `\parshape` setting when the `breaklines` option is enabled for indenting lines that are broken when they are too long.

From a glance at the code I'd say using both packages in conjunction is fine as long as no `lstlisting` occurs in a paragraph that has to be wrapped for a `wrapfigure`. This warning doesn't show up if you use a `lstlisting` without the `breaklines` option in such a paragraph, but the result is still wrong.

On the other hand, using `\lstinline` should be fine in all cases, even if it is too long to fit on the current line. You may get a lot of warnings in this case, the output should be still correct, because `\lstinline` text is broken by the standard line-breaking algorithm and doesn't make use of paragraph shapes by itself.

If you want to get rid of these warnings, after you've made sure it is reported unnecessarily, you can use the following switches `\DisableConflictWarning` and `\EnableConflictWarning` to suppress and later re-enable the warning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\lstset{breaklines=true, basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\makeatletter
\let\origWF@conflict=\WF@conflict
\newcommand\DisableConflictWarning{\let\WF@conflict=\relax}
\newcommand\EnableConflictWarning{\let\WF@conflict=\origWF@conflict}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{wrapfigure}

\DisableConflictWarning
Etiam ac quam dui. \lstinline{test test test test test test} Etiam ac quam dui. Etiam ac quam dui. Etiam ac quam dui. Etiam ac quam dui. Etiam ac quam dui. Etiam ac quam dui. Etiam ac quam dui. Etiam ac quam dui. Etiam ac quam dui.

\end{document}
```

> [image]

In my option, `listings` should never set `\parshape` on `\lstinline`. A proper fix would therefore have to be made in the package code. I don't see a way to patch the current `Init` hook from outside the package.